# Is it worth the effort to overhaul a 95 integra starter?

Tags: starter, integra

If you have performed this procedure on an Integra starter, please state this in your response.  Any lessons-learned or pitfalls to avoid are appreciated.  A new is at from advanced is ~$140

Is it worth the time and effort (just the brushes to replace?) or after 22 years of service should I replace it with a new starter?  Here is what is involved (high level):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 30 years of repairing these units I have never found one to have brushes and commutators that were worn beyond the service limit. The failure in these units is the solenoid contacts. These are not shown in the supplied picture. These contacts take a beating; they generally last about 100k miles. Almost all these starters can be repaired by replacement of the two contacts and the plunger. Our standard repair is to replace just these parts, clean it well, lubricated as indicated by the procedure and then return it to service. We have done hundreds with this method and have not had one return for other problems. We have replaced contacts twice on a few.

The newer Denso starter designs are quite different and need a more comprehensive repair.

Comment: I've replace the brushes on an SBC starter motor before. $5 worth of brushes, about 20 minutes work, and it was good as new. I agree with you about the solenoid contacts ... those things take a huge beating. I'm surprised they last as long as they do, but they are tough little doodads.

Comment: Great comment.  I put 'solenoid contact' into an advanced automotive search and returned nothing.  Am I using the right search term?  I'm not certain if I can find the parts.

Comment: Try the search phrase "SOLENOID CONTACT PLUNGER SET DENSO Nippondenso" ... I found something on eBay which would work for you, I believe. It may take a little bit of searching. Only took me about two minutes to find something which looked right. Make sure you put your car info in the search terms to narrow it down.

Comment: @Fredwilson: I have decided to try replacing the soleoid contacts and the parts arrived today.  I have a new question and look forward to seeing any replies / guidane you may have: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42360/95-integra-ls-starter-procedure-to-replace-plunger-and-starter

Comment: Plunger & contact replacement has breathed new life into the Integra: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42360/95-integra-ls-starter-procedure-to-replace-plunger-and-starter