# 95 Integra LS Starter: Procedure to replace plunger and starter

Tags: starter, integra

A 30 year starter repair veteran indicated [advised](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42246/is-it-worth-the-effort-to-overhaul-a-95-integra-starter) that:

> The failure in these units is the solenoid contacts. These contacts
>   take a beating; they generally last about 100k miles. Almost all these
>   starters can be repaired by replacement of the two contacts and the
>   plunger. Our standard repair is to replace just these parts, clean it
>   well, lubricated as indicated by the procedure and then return it to
>   service.

The [repair kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007FR89FY) arrived today and I will remove the starter.  I am seeking guidance from someone that has done this before (preferably an Integra starter).  Specifically if there is a good procedure on the web (URL link appreciated) or a good video.

I have [attempted to search youtube:](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=integra%20starter%20rebuild) and found a video [Denso Starter Repair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWm8j1SkUD8).  I am assuming the OEM starter is a Denso.  If you have performed this procedure, **I would be interested in any constructive comments regarding this video or recommendations for other videos / web links.**  Please state if you have experience: double bonus if the experience is with an Integra starter.

## UPDATE

The contacts \ plunger were replaced and the starter was installed: started on first try.

The new plunger had to be cut to match the old plunger.  Note the pitting in the old plunger (22 years of service):

[image: New plunger rod had to be cut to size:]

New contact (right) is smooth and old contact (left) is pitted: 
[image]

New plunger and new contacts:
[image]

Procedure in the YouTube video: [**Replacing starter solenoid contacts (NipponDenso)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwokxzjlYcQ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### NOTICE:

I've not done this work to the starter you have listed.

I can tell you from watching the video and from practical experience which I've had doing similar, this is a **straightforward, easily accomplished task.** The hardest part of the whole procedure is pulling the starter off of the engine. While you are not replacing the brushes in the starter motor, you are taking care of the major wear parts in the starter.

Reasons I'd do this myself:

1. It's an easy job. If you can follow instructions and pay attention to detail, even someone with minimal mechanical ability and a basic set of hand tools should be able to accomplish this.
2. Cost of self repair versus full part replacement. If this doesn't work, you're only out $10 or so. A new starter is going to cost a whole bunch more. It's worth the risk and time to try this even if it ultimately fails in the end.
3. Time involved is minimal. Even done slowly, this is, at most, a two hour job. If you were replacing with a new starter, this job is just a bit longer.
4. Satisfaction when it's done.

All-in-all, just get it done. I wish more starters had the availability for such repair kits. In most cases you cannot find just a solenoid for starters, so are forced to purchase the entire starter to fix your issues. This provides a great alternative.

Comment: @PAULSTER2:  thank you for the encouragement.  Always pleased to hear from you.

Comment: @PAULSTER2: This was a straightforward task and bench tested the repair  at Advanced Automotive to test the efficacy of the repair.

Answer (score 2):

1. Disconnect the battery before doing any work. The solenoid is directly connected to the battery. Should you short it during removal/installation you will get a nice rain of sparks, a glowing hot spanner and a good chance of experiencing a extremely fast oxidizing (burning) car.
2. Speaking from experience: Clean up your shed before disassembling the starter. Chances are that some small parts (usual suspect: the springs from the brushes) will disappear in the darkest corner of your workshop.
3. It is a good occasion to lube some hard-to-reach parts: Mostly the shaft needs some love in the form of an slight coat of engine oil (two drops from the dipstick on the place where the gear is supposed to move), also the plain bearings could need lubrication (synthetic grease)

Comment: Experience and lessons-learned are appreciated: thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have had experience re-building starter motors from ride-on lawnmowers right up to large heavy duty starter motors for diesel engines in tractors and Heavy good vehicles. This is, as explained by others, easy enough to do, just take pictures as you take it apart, lay all the parts out in the order they came apart - even pay attention to bolts as some are different lengths, then re-assemble, tighten and test before you fit it. Good luck.