# Diagnosing why 95 Integra does not start

Tags: starter, integra

I am seeking simple / easy tests to diagnose the cause(s) of non-starting Integra

## BACKGROUND

A 95 [Integra starter was refurbished](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42360/95-integra-ls-starter-procedure-to-replace-plunger-and-starter) in 2016.  The Integra was wired to a pickup with battery jumper cables:

- starter will not turn over and does not click
- pickup's alternator does not drop in pitch when attempting to jumpstart Integra
- replacement with new battery does not start the Integra
- lights / dashboard light up and cable terminals were wire brushed.
- 1/2 tank of gas

This article indicates [5 common reasons](https://www.fiix.io/car-advice/articles/5-reasons-why-your-car-won%27t-start) for starting failure.  I think I can eliminate:

- battery: new battery was tried: no joy.  2016 battery was re-installed (12.5V connected)
- gasoline \ fuel: 1/2 a tank indicated

## QUESTIONS

1. What are the easy / simple tests that can eliminate or confirm components in the starting sequence?
2. Is there a simple test that can confirm eliminate the battery wiring (radio, headlights and instrument panel light up)?
3. Given the context above, is it reasonable to conclude that alternator is preventing engine startup?

Lessons learned and pitfalls are always appreciated.

Comment: Can you get to the solenoid of the starter easily without taking the starter out? If so, can you jump the starter lead to see if the starter kicks over? If it will turn the engine over, you should be able to eliminate the starter as the issue. If it doesn't it points right to it.